# python3.6 variable substitution in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, substitution, python-3.6

I have the following syntax that should be correct in Python3.6

```
for k in current:
        new_key = f'{key}.{k}' if len(key) > 0 else k
        flatten(current[k], new_key, result)
```

the "f" before the string in new_key makes all the following code colored in red.
Is there any mistake in the code? I'm able to run it without errors?

Comment: jupyter notebook does not show errors in the input box where you type the code. Since its running correctly you can ignore it as a formatting thing.

Comment: I do, but I'd like to see the code colored correctly!

Comment: if you wanna get rid of this color maybe you can try this form of string substitution `'{0}.{1}'.format(key, k)` its basically the same thing